# Solve mean reverting SDE with RBF's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-modeling, change-of-basis

I am working on a mean reverting stochastic differential equation in this form $dC(t)=(c_{in}-c(t))\frac{r_{in}}{V}dt+\frac{r_{in}}{V}\alpha dB_t$ where $B_t $ is a standard wiener process (Brownian motion),as a simple form $$\frac{dC}{dt}=\theta(\mu-c)+\sigma \frac{dB_t}{dt}$$
I am trying to solve it by radial basis functions $$\phi_i=\sqrt{||c(t)-c(t_i)||+k^2}$$ where k is a shape parameter, and $\frac{dB_t}{dt}$ is Gaussian noise

so I  did like below

$$c(t)\sim\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i\phi_i\\c(t)\sim\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2}
\\c'(t)\sim \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\frac{(c(t)-c(t_i))}{\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2}}$$ so I putthem into equation
$$\frac{dC}{dt}=(c_{in}-c)\frac{r_{in}}{V}+\frac{r_{in}}{V}\alpha \frac{dB_t}{dt}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\frac{(c(t)-c(t_i))}{\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2}}=(c_{in}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2})\frac{r_{in}}{V}+\frac{r_{in}}{V}\alpha \frac{dB_t}{dt}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(\frac{(c(t)-c(t_i))}{\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2}}+\sqrt{(c(t)-c(t_i))^2+k^2})\frac{r_{in}}{V})=\frac{r_{in}}{V}(c_{in}+\alpha \frac{dB_t}{dt})$$ then turn it to $$
a_{i,j}=\frac{(c(t_j)-c(t_i))}{\sqrt{(c(t_j)-c(t_i))^2+k^2}}+\sqrt{(c(t_j)-c(t_i))^2+k^2})\frac{r_{in}}{V}
\\ \begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}
 \end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
 w_1 \\
 w_2\\
 \vdots\\
w_n
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{r_{in}}{V}(c_{in}+\alpha \dfrac{dB_{t_1}}{dt})\\
 \frac{r_{in}}{V}(c_{in}+\alpha \dfrac{dB_{t_2}}{dt})\\
 \vdots \\
\frac{r_{in}}{V}(c_{in}+\alpha \dfrac{dB_{t_n}}{dt})
 \end{pmatrix} 
 $$Now my first question is :
$$\textit{Is my work true ?}$$second question: Is this true that, I put $\frac {dB_{t_n}}{dt}\sim $ rand(0,1)?

Comment: You seem to have a replaced a simple linear SDE with a messy nonlinear system of SDEs, it would be nice to have a bit more motivation as to why you would want to do this? Why you think the process $C_t$ should have a nice decomposition in terms of RBF etc. it would seem more natural to switch to the associated FP PDE and then take a basis function expansion of the transition pdf. What you are doing may still be a worthwhile exercise, but for the linear case the solution is a Gaussian process and has a natural basis decomposition in terms of its RKHS